# Sharing a file handle between threads

Tags: rust

I'm using the log crate to do some basic logging and I want the log messages to go to either a file or stderr. I have created a struct to hold the output destination but get the following error:

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Send` is not implemented for the type `std::io::Write + 'static` [E0277]
    impl log::Log for MyLogger {
        fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        }

        fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        }
    ...
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: `std::io::Write + 'static` cannot be sent between threads safely
note: required because it appears within the type `Box<std::io::Write + 'static>`
note: required because it appears within the type `MyLogger`
note: required by `log::Log`
```

Here's the code I put together to test this:

```
extern crate log;

use log::{LogRecord, LogMetadata, LogLevelFilter, SetLoggerError};
use std::io::{LineWriter, stderr, Write};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct MyLogger {
    out_stream: Arc<Mutex<Box<Write>>>
}

impl log::Log for MyLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
    }
}

impl MyLogger {
    fn init(outfile: String) -> Result<(), SetLoggerError> {
        let logfile = match OpenOptions::new().create(true).append(true).open(&outfile) {
                Ok(f)  => Box::new(LineWriter::new(f)) as Box<Write>,
                Err(_) => Box::new(LineWriter::new(stderr())) as Box<Write>
            };

        log::set_logger(|max_log_level| {
            max_log_level.set(LogLevelFilter::Warn);
            Box::new(MyLogger{out_stream: logfile})         
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyLogger::init("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[The `Log` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/trait.Log.html) is a subtrait of `Send` and `Sync`:

```
pub trait Log: Sync + Send {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool;
    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord);
}
```

In order to implement `Log` for your own type, your type must be `Send` and `Sync` as well.

However, your `MyLogger` struct is neither `Send` nor `Sync`, because the `Box<Write>` could contain a non-`Send` type. We can restrict the box to containing a `Send` type:

```
struct MyLogger {
    out_stream: Arc<Mutex<Box<Write + Send>>>
}
```

This is enough to make `MyLogger` both `Send` and `Sync`. Here's your code with this fix and other necessary fixes applied:

```
extern crate log;

use log::{LogRecord, LogMetadata, LogLevelFilter, SetLoggerError};
use std::io::{LineWriter, stderr, Write};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct MyLogger {
    out_stream: Arc<Mutex<Box<Write + Send>>>
}

impl log::Log for MyLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl MyLogger {
    fn init(outfile: &str) -> Result<(), SetLoggerError> {
        let logfile = match OpenOptions::new().create(true).append(true).open(outfile) {
                Ok(f)  => Box::new(LineWriter::new(f)) as Box<Write + Send>,
                Err(_) => Box::new(LineWriter::new(stderr())) as Box<Write + Send>
            };

        log::set_logger(|max_log_level| {
            max_log_level.set(LogLevelFilter::Warn);
            Box::new(MyLogger { out_stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(logfile)) })
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyLogger::init("");
}
```

Comment: Thank-you that compiles ok. What is still puzzling me is that using `out_stream: Arc<Mutex<Box<Write + Send>>>` is saying that the object that is wrapped in Arc, Mutex and Box is guaranteed to have the `Write` and `Send` traits. However, in  this example we are wrapping a `LineWriter` which has only `Write`. Therefore this guarantee is not met so I'm puzzled as to how this compiles.

Comment: The documentation doesn't show the types for which `Send` and `Sync` is implemented automatically by the compiler. It only shows explicit implementations (whether positive or negative) mentioned in the code. `LineWriter` does in fact implement `Send` if the wrapped writer is `Send` ([demonstation](http://is.gd/c4EhG4)).